# Why is the code showing NameError for the following code

Tags: python-3.x, reduce

```
from functools import reduce
li = [5, 8, 10, 20, 50, 100] 
sum = reduce((lambda x,y: x*(1/2**li.index(x))) + y*(1/2**li.index(y)) , li)
print(sum)
```

Error that is being shown is NameError: name 'y' is not defined

Comment: you are accessing `y` outside of your lambda function.

Comment: oh thanks that was so silly of me. but now its showing ValueError: 9.0 is not in list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not override sum as it is a builtin, but the problem is not there.
The problem is with the parentheses. You close the lambda parenthesis before the plus sign. You can try something like that:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x*(1/2**a.index(x)) + y*(1/2**a.index(y)), li)
```

Comment: oh thanks that was so silly of me. but now its showing ValueError: 9.0 is not in list

Comment: I didn't do the math but I guess that one intermediate result of the reduction gives 9.0, and you're searching 9.0 in `li` wich is not there. You might need to rethink your algorithm.

Comment: i am not super sure about reduce. but it does not search anything. it doesnt make any sense to me of why there should be a 9 in li

Comment: It is not about reduce, but you have `li.index(x)` (and same with y) which searches an element in a list and returns its index, so you search x in li. At some point x equals 9.0, that's why it fails.